# A calculus problem

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, periodic-functions

**Question:**

Suppose that $u(x,t)$ is continuous, together with its first and second partial derivatives; suppose that $u$ and its first partial derivatives are periodic in $x$ of period $1,$ and suppose that $u_{tt}=u_{xx}.$ Prove that
$$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left(u_t^2(x,t)+u_x^2(x,t)\right)\text{d}x$$
is a constant, independent of $t.$

**Here is my solution:**

Since $u(x,t)$ and its $t-$partial derivative is continuous, we can differentiate as follows.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E'(t)&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^12u_tu_{tt}+2u_xu_{xt}\text{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1u_tu_{xx}+u_xu_{xt}\text{d}x\\
&=u_xu_t\bigg|^1_0-\int_0^1u_xu_{tx}\text{d}x+u_tu_x\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1u_tu_{xx}\text{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^1u_xu_{tx}\text{d}x-\int_0^1u_tu_{xx}\text{d}x
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Combining the first and third line from the bottom to see that
$$E'(t)=0\quad \forall t.$$
And thus $E(t)$ is a constant.

Then I just realised that I haven't used the periodic condition. Was I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implicitly used the periodicity conditions to conclude that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u_xu_t\bigg|^1_0 = u_tu_x\bigg|_0^1 = 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
From the second to the third line.